# "Redirect many times" I frame tag issue

Tags: html, wordpress, redirect, iframe, elementor

I have a website login page with ASP.net I want to add it as an I frame on another  WordPress website with Elementor but it gave me a "redirect many times error".

`your text`

this is the HTML code that I have used but it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.